# Possible to implement draggable view with Xamarin Forms without using native Andriod/IOS code?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Is it possible to implement a draggable view with Xamarin View? Is there basically an event that I can use that gets triggered when a finger is pressed on the screen, then moved and then released without having to use native Android/iOS code? I don't mean a swipe event, I know this exists. I am looking for a event so I can let the user be able to drag a rectangle across the screen for example.

Looked for it on the internet, but can only seem to find just normal Touch, Swipe and Tap events. (Although I found it is possible using native Android/IOS code.

Comment: I think your best bet may be to look at an external lib in order to get access to some of this functionality cross platform. MR.Gestures could allow you detect a down gesture, when you get that event track the movement and translate the view on screen, and stop when you get the up gesture. Vanilla Xamarin Forms doesn't have that level of support for gestures to my knowledge.

Comment: There seems to be no off-the-shelf controls to implement this functionality, but you can do it with the CustomRenderer, and I think the third-party libraries are written through this as well

Comment: if you want,i could give you an sample